# Intercalar vetores em C

Tags: c

Pessoal tenho que desenvolver um código que leia o tamanho de 2 vetores dps os elementos dele(esses vetores são crescentes), transforme em um unico vetor(não tem que estar ordenado), e depois usando a função de intercalar, transforme em um vetor ordenado e printar ele.
A duvida é a seguinte, é possivel fazer isso sem utilizar o MergeSort? somente utilizando a função " Intercalar"?? Tentei varias coisas aqui mas sempre tem 2 elementos que deviam estar no começo que estão ficando no final.

Edit: Resumindo, a duvida mesmo é se é possivel fazer isso que o exercicio pede sem usar nenhum algoritmo de ordenação, somente a função "Intercalar" que no caso seria intercalar o vetor da posição 0 ate meio-1 com o vetor meio ate tamanho-1
Segue o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int intercala(int *v, int inicio, int n, int t){

    int v1 = inicio;
    int fim = (n+t)-1;
    int meio = (n+t)/2;
    int v2 = meio+1;
    int i,j;
    int tamanho = fim-inicio+1;
    int vet[tamanho];


    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){

     if(v[v1] <= v[v2]){
        vet[i]=v[v1++];
     }
        else{
        vet[i]=v[v2++];
        }
    }
   while(v1<=meio){
       vet[i++] = v[v1++];

   }

    while(v2<=fim){
       vet[i++] = v[v2++];

   }


    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        printf("%d ", vet[i]);
    }


    return 0;


}





int main (){


int n, t, i;

printf("Tamanho do primeiro vetor\n");
scanf("%d", &n);


printf("Tamanho do segundo vetor\n");
scanf("%d", &t);

int v[t+n];
printf("elementos do primeiro vetor\n");
for(i=0; i <n; i++){

    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
 printf("Elementos do segundo vetor\n");
for(i=n; i <(n+t); i++){
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}




intercala(v, 0, n, t);




return 0;



}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode resolver isso facilmente com o Bubble Sort, porém é muito lento, ou ainda, se os vetores forem compostos apenas por valores positivos você pode aplicar o Counting sort, um algoritmo muito bom para esse tipo de caso.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void countingSort(int *vet, int vetSize, int maior) {
    int *aux = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (maior + 1));
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < vetSize; i++) {
        aux[vet[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < maior + 1; i++) {
        if (aux[i] != 0) {
            while (aux[i] > 0) {
                vet[j] = i;
                aux[i]--;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(aux);
}

void bubbleSort(int *vet, int vetSize) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < vetSize - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vetSize - i - 1; j++) {
            if (vet[j] > vet[j + 1]) {
                int aux = vet[j];
                vet[j] = vet[j + 1];
                vet[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, t, i, maior = 1;

    printf("Tamanho do primeiro vetor\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Tamanho do segundo vetor\n");
    scanf("%d", &t);

    int v[t + n];
    printf("elementos do primeiro vetor\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        if (v[i] > maior) {
            maior = v[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Elementos do segundo vetor\n");
    for(i = n; i < (n + t); i++){
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        if (v[i] > maior) {
            maior = v[i];
        }
    }
    //countingSort(v, n + t, maior);
    bubbleSort(v, n + t);
    for (i = 0; i < n + t; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Opa, então eu cheguei a dar uma olhada nos algoritmos de ordenação, mas  a duvida mesmo é se é possivel fazer isso que o exercicio pede sem usar nenhum algoritmo de ordenação, somente a função "Intercalar" que no caso seria intercalar o vetor da posição  0 ate meio-1 com o vetor meio ate  tamanho-1"

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui criar uma função que faz isso em O(n + m):

```
//n é o tamanho do vetor a, m é o tamanho do vetor b
int *intercala(int *a, int *b, int n, int m){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int *c = (int*)malloc((n + m)*sizeof(int));
    int k = 0;
    while((i + j) < (n + m)){
        if(i >= n){
            for (; j < m; j++, k++){
                c[k] = b[j];
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(j >= m){
            for (; i < n; i++, k++){
                c[k] = a[i];
            }
            break;
        }
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            c[k] = a[i++];

        else 
            c[k] = b[j++];

        k++;
    } 
    return c;
}
```

Dados os dois vetores a, b com tamanhos n, m, respectivamente, basta você percorrer os dois vetores ao mesmo tempo usando índices i, j vendo qual é menor. Daí quando você pega um elemento de qualquer vetor, basta incrementar o índice usado. Se você percorrer um vetor até o final, basta pegar os elementos restantes do outro vetor.